# discriminator but not int single table

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm quite new here so my apologies if I've done mistakes presentation of orthographics.

I would like to have 3 tables. Two are the subclass of the last one.
For that I want to use a discriminator for the subclass but not in a single table.

Example:

```
 
 abstract class     concrete class   concrete_class
 table_one           table_two        table_three
  id                    info             info
  info_For both         info             info
  type (table_two or table_three)
```

I didn't find any informations in the documentation. (Maybe not understood)

Thanks for help,

Gegko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

Create your main abstract class *EntityA*, I defined the Inheretance by Join, all tables will share same PK.

Then also define the column will act as discriminator **type**, and the type of column data.

On each subclass you have to define the real value of your discriminator column, so hibernate know which Object need to build, if *EntityB* or *EntityC*.

That's all

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_one")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType =    DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class EntityA {


@Entity
@Table(name = "table_two")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
public class EntityB extends EntityA {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_three")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "C")
public class EntityC extends EntityA {
...
}
```

Here official doc http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator

Comment: Thanks, i'll test your solution :) 
Look quite simple.. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Gegko great, let me know if you can make it work correctly

Comment: @Gegko some lights??

Comment: Yes i've not tested yet ! 
I inform you as soon as possible if it works

Comment: @Gegko great! could you validate the response? so other community member could use it too? :)

Comment: How to do that :) ?

Comment: lol at left side of my response there is a white tick, if you click will change to green, thats the way to say, the response is ok, also you can click on upvote-downvote if you think is a right answer even if you didnt ask it